# Unable to insert smart pointer into map

Tags: c++

I am trying to insert my smart pointer, `p_pointer<foo>` pointing towards a `foo` class into map, however the program would not compile. Therefore I tried to use a normal pointer `foo*` and the program does compile. So far, I have been able to use the `p_pointer` like a normal pointer without any issue so I am surprised that this does not work. If anyone can explain to me why this would not work...

```
#include <iostream>
#include<map>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class p_pointer
{
public:
    T* cp;
    size_t* refptr;

    size_t* counter()
    {
        return refptr;
    }
//default constructor
    p_pointer():cp(0),refptr(new size_t(1)) {}
    p_pointer(T*t):cp(t),refptr(new size_t(1)) {}
//copy constructor
    p_pointer (const p_pointer&s):cp(s.cp),refptr(s.refptr)
    {
        refptr=s.refptr;
        cp=s.cp;
        *refptr=*refptr+1;
    }
//destructor
    ~p_pointer()
    {

        if(--*refptr==0)
        {
            delete cp;
            delete refptr;
        }
    }

//assignment operator
    p_pointer&operator=(const p_pointer&s)
    {
        ++*s.refptr;
//freeing the left hand size if it is the last one
        if(--*refptr==0)
        {
            delete cp;
            delete refptr;
        }
        cp=s.cp;
        refptr=s.refptr;
    }

    operator bool()
    {
        return cp;
    }

    T*&operator->()
    {
        if(cp)
            return cp;

        else throw std::runtime_error("uninitialized player");
    }

    T operator*()
    {
        if(cp)
            return *cp;
        else throw std::runtime_error("uninitialized player");
    }
};

class foo
{};
```

Method 1 (works)

```
int main()
{
    map<foo*,int> x;
    foo* y=new foo();
    x[y]=1;
}
```

Method 2 (does not work)

```
int main()
{
    map<p_pointer<foo>,int> x;
    p_pointer<foo> y=new foo();
    x[y]=1;
}
```

The error message is:
This is my first time posting an error message. I just copied all the content from build messages and paste it into here. Please let me know if this is not the optimal way

```
||=== Build: Debug in trial 821 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h||In instantiation of 'bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = p_pointer<foo>]':|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_map.h|498|required from 'std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = p_pointer<foo>; _Tp = int; _Compare = std::less<p_pointer<foo> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const p_pointer<foo>, int> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = int; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = p_pointer<foo>]'|
C:\trial 821\main.cpp|80|required from here|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h|371|error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'const p_pointer<foo>' and 'const p_pointer<foo>')|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h|371|note: candidates are:|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h|371|note: operator<(int, int) <built-in>|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h|371|note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'const p_pointer<foo>' to 'int'|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_pair.h|220|note: template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr bool std::operator<(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_pair.h|220|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h|371|note:   'const p_pointer<foo>' is not derived from 'const std::pair<_T1, _T2>'|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h|298|note: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h|298|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h|371|note:   'const p_pointer<foo>' is not derived from 'const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>'|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h|348|note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h|348|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h|371|note:   'const p_pointer<foo>' is not derived from 'const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>'|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h|1072|note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator<(const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::move_iterator<_IteratorR>&)|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h|1072|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h|371|note:   'const p_pointer<foo>' is not derived from 'const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>'|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h|1078|note: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator<(const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>&)|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h|1078|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h|371|note:   'const p_pointer<foo>' is not derived from 'const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>'|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h|2588|note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h|2588|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h|371|note:   'const p_pointer<foo>' is not derived from 'const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>'|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h|2600|note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h|2600|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h|371|note:   'const p_pointer<foo>' is not derived from 'const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>'|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h|2612|note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const _CharT*, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h|2612|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h|371|note:   mismatched types 'const _CharT*' and 'p_pointer<foo>'|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_tree.h|980|note: template<class _Key, class _Val, class _KeyOfValue, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&)|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_tree.h|980|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h|371|note:   'const p_pointer<foo>' is not derived from 'const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>'|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\array|242|note: template<class _Tp, unsigned int _Nm> bool std::operator<(const std::array<_Tp, _Nm>&, const std::array<_Tp, _Nm>&)|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\array|242|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h|371|note:   'const p_pointer<foo>' is not derived from 'const std::array<_Tp, _Nm>'|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\tuple|857|note: template<class ... _TElements, class ... _UElements> constexpr bool std::operator<(const std::tuple<_Args1 ...>&, const std::tuple<_Args2 ...>&)|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\tuple|857|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h|371|note:   'const p_pointer<foo>' is not derived from 'const std::tuple<_Args1 ...>'|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_map.h|1017|note: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_map.h|1017|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h|371|note:   'const p_pointer<foo>' is not derived from 'const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>'|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_multimap.h|920|note: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_multimap.h|920|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
C:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h|371|note:   'const p_pointer<foo>' is not derived from 'const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 3 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Why are you writing your own smart pointer? Just for fun? Or do the ones in the standard library already (e.g. std::shared_ptr) not have some feature that you need?

Comment: @FlightOdyssey This is my first time posting an error message. It looks super messy so im not sure if this is what you are asking for. As to your first question, i read about smart pointer at a book and was using it till now. I never know standard has a smart pointer available already... Will definitely look that up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem can be found in the error message: `no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'const p_pointer' and 'const p_pointer')|`. In order to use `map` with a custom type (`p_pointer` in this case), that type needs to declare a comparison operator `<` which is used to sort the keys in the map. You'll need to implement the `<` operator, and that should fix this error. (Other errors may show up to replace it though.)

Again, I would recommend just using the existing `std::shared_ptr` rather than re-implementing it yourself, unless you have some reason not to do so.